# Ajuda para formatar data em blade laravel

Tags: laravel

preciso formatar a data para 00-00-0000, o codigo abaixo é view do laravel .blade.php

```
<td class="col-sm-2" data-bind="text: created_at"></td>
```

created_at é campo do banco de dados.

apenas para ilustrar, para limitar caracteres eu consegui assim, mas com data não consigo

```
<td class="col-sm-3" data-bind="text: plot ? plot.trunc(150) : null"></td>
```

agradeço qualquer ajuda

Comment: Acredito que faltam informações na sua pergunta, eu nunca havia visto esse atributo `data-bind` no laravel, por exemplo, e após uma breve pesquisa encontrei essa api js: http://knockoutjs.com/index.html

Comment: Me vem ainda outra coisa em mente, aparentemente você quer somente mostrar o campo vindo do banco de dados, formatado correto? Porque não faz algo parecido com [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441395/how-to-change-default-format-at-created-at-and-updated-at-value-laravel)? Desse modo você diminui a carga de js no seu front-end, e já que você vai buscar o dado no bd, já o traz formatado

Comment: Claro, que isso vai de gosto, mas quando quero formatar algum dado para exibir no front-end eu prefiro fazer diretamente no meu model, exp:   na minha `class product` tenho uma `public function formatedPriece()` que possui o seguinte código: `{ return ( is_null($this->price) ? trans('price-empty') : "R$ ".number_format($this->price, 2, ',', '.'); }`

Comment: Além do Laravel está utilizando outras coisas ... poderia disponibilizar esse código na integra?

Comment: o problema é que esta parte é toda  knockoutjs e o seu exemplo como ou outras coisas que tentei não funcionaram. pedi ajuda no forum  knockoutjs